# How did I get near-infinite magicka?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the middle of doing the Mages College quests in Skyrim I noticed that my magicka bar was not appearing at all despite casting spells. I found that I could cast the Flames spell indefinitely without my magicka ever draining. I looked at my Current Effects and saw that I had three extra Magicka Regen bonuses, but there was no indication of where they had come from. So I was pretty much indestructible for the next hour of playtime or so before the effects wore off.

Where would these effects have come from? Would it have been anything to do with the Eye of Magnus (which I "Activated"), just a glitch, or something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The quest that gave you infinite magicka regeneration is [Out of Balance](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Out_of_Balance)

From the UESP site:

> When cleaning the foci, a bugged two hour buff may be placed on you that increases magicka regeneration immensely. It is possible to get multiples of this buff during the quest. In the active effects category, it appears as "Fortify Magicka". Selecting it reveals it as "Drain Magicka, +25 Fortify Magicka for 2 hours". It doesn't appear to increase magicka capacity at all (as listed on the skills screen), but increases magicka regeneration rate instead.
>
> Some players have reported that the buff remains much longer than the stated 2 hours. In this case, the buff(s) can be removed by opening the character editor with the "showracemenu" console command (on PC) and closing it again. This will also remove other temporary buffs, such as blessings, and enchanted apparel will need to be re-equipped to restore their effects. (v1.1.21.0 of game)

Comment: I did that quest around that time so pretty sure this is correct.

Comment: For me it stayed active until I reached the next level. Then it went away even if I didn't take the level yet.

Comment: It happened to me right after I got the mystical tuning gloves, it lasted about 4 hours for me and my magicka wouldn't even move when casting my strongest spells

Answer (score 5):

This is potentially a bug in the **Under Saarthal** quest given to you by **Tolfdir** in the Mage College questline.

> - Equipping the Saarthal Amulet can cause players to have infinite magicka.
>
> **Source:** [Skyrim Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Under_Saarthal)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: He's asking about the infinite magica regen bug, which is not this quest.  But you are right, this quest can also give you a similar bug.

Answer (score 2):

I found there was at least one place in the Mage College quests where I also had nearly infinite mana.  I believe it's part of the questline, and the effect seemed to disappear after I turned in one of the quests a bit later.

Comment: its a quest from the master of illsion guy after the frist quest main mages guild but i cant ever get it back again supposly it gaven ever 3 day (in skyrim)

Answer (score -1):

I used enchanted robes with 80% faster magicka regenarion and 60% more magicka. Together with skilled magicka I could cast for example fireball for 3 consecutive minutes.