# Staff of Magnus Help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was able to do the quest and I'm the arch mage, YAY, but there is a problem. I may just not be waiting a long enough time but after a couple days, my magicka still won't return to normal. Ever since the staff was used on me I have -65 magicka without my equipment but 80 with it, I should have around 280. What should I do? If it's a glitch is there any command I can use to fix it, if it's permanent than I guess that sucks because I was playing a pure mage. If it should slowly come back that would also be nice to know.

Comment: Look under the effects section and see what's giving you the penalties.  It could be something else completely unrelated to the Staff of Magnus.

Comment: Did you Cleanse the Wells for an NPC?  That can give you a really serious magicka debuff, for a massive boost in regen.

Comment: Nelson is referring to the quest [Out of Balance](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Out_of_Balance). I don't see anyone complaining about it reducing their overall magicka total, though. There's a [question about the bug](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42459/how-did-i-get-near-infinite-magicka).

Comment: I would like to hear what the active effects page says before putting any more effort into solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Check your "Active Effects" section of your character. Anything highlighted in red represent the bad/negative effects on your character. If the Staff of Magnus effect is still there go to any of your owned beds and sleep for a 24 hour period. Then return to the arch-mage.

If the problem is not a staff and a serious disease/poison or injury. Use the appropriate potion of "Cure Disease" to cancel the effect.

If the effect is a class effect (like becoming a vampire) you'll have to do a specific mini-quest in order to have the curse lifted.

You can also remove all negative status effects by going and praying at any shrine you'll receive a blessing from that deity. If you have Hearthstone you can build some in the basement of your Manor outside of Falkreath.

Comment: Another option is to try going to a shrine and have the bleesing of any god. When gaining a blessing, all negative effects (except curses and equipment related) are lifted.

Comment: @LucasSant'Anna Absolutely I'll work that into the answer.